# Dynamically pass in name of column based on value from another

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Say I have a dataframe like below.

```
eff_month  eff_date  latest_volume_month_1  latest_volume_month_2  latest_volume_month_3  pct

  1        2022-01-13      55                        60                   70               .5
  2        2022-02-10      40                        50                   60               .1
  3        2022-03-02      30                        50                   70               .2
```

I am trying to create a new column that depending on the eff_month and pct will do some math for the values within the latest_volume_month_{eff_month} and pct.

The math: For the 1st month only take the sum of latest_volume_month_1 and multiple by pct to get vol.
For the 2nd month take the sum of latest_volume_month_1 and latest_volume_month_2 and then multiply by pct.
Third row take the sum of month 1,2,3 and multiply by pct for vol.

The expected output would look something like this.

```
eff_month  eff_date  latest_volume_month_1  latest_volume_month_2  latest_volume_month_3  pct  vol

  1        2022-01-13      55                        60                   70               .5  22.5
  2        2022-02-10      40                        50                   60               .1  9.1
  3        2022-03-02      30                        50                   70               .2  25
```

Comment: I know I could hardcode it using F.when for all 12 months but ideally don't want to do that.

Comment: What is the expected output for the data given?

Comment: @User12345 I fixed my question. Let me know if that doesn't help.